# What does chunk do in Aurelia PLATFORM.moduleName(module, chunk)?

Tags: aurelia

I've read the online documentation and the API documentation in the code.

Online says: "Add the module to a chunk by name"
API says nothing really

What does it add, and what should it be? Can I omit it?